# How to type style property in custom React-Native component when using animation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have component like this:

```
import { type ReactNode } from 'react';
import { Animated, View, Text, type TextProps, type StyleProp, type TextStyle } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './styles';

type CharTextProps = {
  position?: number;
  children: string;
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  mapStyle?: (index: number, chr: string) => StyleProp<TextStyle>;
} & TextProps;


const CharText = ({ mapStyle, style, children, ...restProps }: CharTextProps) => (
  <View style={styles.container} {...restProps}>
    {[...children].map((chr, index) => (
      <Animated.Text key={`${chr}-${index}`} style={[styles.char, style, mapStyle && mapStyle(index, chr)]}>
        {chr}
      </Animated.Text>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

The code was working fine but now I need to animate the value for a given character.
I need code like this to animate the cursor using the border left or right. Like this:

```js
const FakeInput = ({ position = 0, style, value, ...restProps }: FakeInputProps) => {
  const len = value.length;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const color = useColorAnimation(cursor.solid, cursor.transparent) as any;

  return (
    <CharText
      mapStyle={index => [
        style,
        index === len - 1 && position === len && { borderRightColor: color },
        index === position && { borderLeftColor: color },
      ]}
      {...restProps}
    >
      {value}
    </CharText>
  );
};
```

`useColorAnimation` return interpolated value from React-Native animation.

The problem is that I can't style the `mapStyle` function to accept the value from `useColorAnimation` hook, that's why I put any. But I would like to style this properly and don't use any.

This the error I've got when I remove `any`:

```
Type '(index: number) => (false | (ViewStyle & TextStyle) | (number & { __registeredStyleBrand: ViewStyle; } & { __registeredStyleBrand: TextStyle; }) | ... 4 more ... | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type '(index: number, chr: string) => StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
  Type '(false | (ViewStyle & TextStyle) | (number & { __registeredStyleBrand: ViewStyle; } & { __registeredStyleBrand: TextStyle; }) | (RecursiveArray<...> & RecursiveArray<...>) | { ...; } | { ...; } | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<TextStyle>'.
    Type '(false | (ViewStyle & TextStyle) | (number & { __registeredStyleBrand: ViewStyle; } & { __registeredStyleBrand: TextStyle; }) | (RecursiveArray<...> & RecursiveArray<...>) | { ...; } | { ...; } | null | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'RecursiveArray<Falsy | TextStyle | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle>>'.
      The types returned by 'pop()' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'false | (ViewStyle & TextStyle) | (number & { __registeredStyleBrand: ViewStyle; } & { __registeredStyleBrand: TextStyle; }) | (RecursiveArray<...> & RecursiveArray<...>) | { ...; } | { ...; } | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Falsy | TextStyle | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle> | RecursiveArray<Falsy | TextStyle | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle>> | readonly (Falsy | ... 1 more ... | RegisteredStyle<...>)[]'.
          Type '{ borderRightColor: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<string | number>; borderLeftColor?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Falsy | TextStyle | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle> | RecursiveArray<Falsy | TextStyle | RegisteredStyle<TextStyle>> | readonly (Falsy | ... 1 more ... | RegisteredStyle<...>)[]'.
            Type '{ borderRightColor: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<string | number>; borderLeftColor?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'TextStyle'.
              Types of property 'borderRightColor' are incompatible.
                Type 'AnimatedInterpolation<string | number>' is not assignable to type 'ColorValue | undefined'.
```

I've tried using:

```js
type CharTextProps {
   ...
mapStyle?: (index: number, chr: string) => (StyleProp<TextStyle> | Animated.AnimatedProps<StyleProp<TextStyle>>);
} & TextProps;
```

But this doesn't work and I got the same error.

One NOTE: is that the code is inside Screen using `Drawer.Screen` from `@react-navigation`. So the component is never unmounted unless the file is modified and Live Reload triggers.