# ReactNative animation runs only when I modify the file while the app is running in dev mode

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a blinking cursor animation in my ReactNative app:

```js
const useColorAnimation = (startColor: ColorValue, endColor: ColorValue) => {
  const coloAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(coloAnim, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
        Animated.timing(coloAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
      ])
    );

    console.log('start');
    animation.start();

    return () => {
      console.log('stop');
      animation.stop();
    };
  }, [coloAnim]);

  return coloAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [startColor as string, endColor as string],
  });
};

const FakeInput = ({ position = 0, style, value, ...restProps }: FakeInputProps) => {
  const len = value.length;
  // Hack
  // We are using `as any` becasue we had problems with proper typing for style
  // that can have interpolated values inside CharText.Animated component.
  // check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77157324/387194
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const color = useColorAnimation(cursor.solid, cursor.transparent) as any;

  return (
    <CharText.Animated
      mapStyle={index => [
        style,
        index === len - 1 && position === len && { borderRightColor: color },
        index === position && { borderLeftColor: color },
      ]}
      {...restProps}
    >
      {value}
    </CharText.Animated>
  );
};
```

The problem is that the animation doesn't work unless I modify the file that contains the
FakeInput component and the app refreshes that component while the app is running.

Does anyone know why the animation doesn't run after build or reload?

I use Expo on Xubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was probably because React was updating the component when the state changed which didn't restart the animation. My animation was dynamic when the position state changed the animation was in a different place so the animation had to restart on each state change.

To fix this I first used the unique key on a component that uses the animation:

this is the code I used to fix the issue, I've added a dependency to the animation hook which restarts the animation on each state change.

```
const useColorAnimation = (startColor: ColorValue, endColor: ColorValue, dependency: any[] = []) => {
  const coloAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(coloAnim, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
        Animated.timing(coloAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }),
      ])
    );

    animation.start();

    return () => {
      animation.stop();
    };
  }, [coloAnim, ...dependency]);

  return coloAnim.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [startColor as string, endColor as string],
  });
};

const FakeInput = ({ position = 0, style, value, ...restProps }: FakeInputProps) => {
  const len = value.length;
  // Hack
  // We are using `as any` becasue we had problems with proper typing for style
  // that can have interpolated values inside CharText.Animated component.
  // check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77157324/387194
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  const color = useColorAnimation(cursor.solid, cursor.transparent, [position, len]) as any;

  return (
    <CharText.Animated
      mapStyle={index => [
        style,
        index === len - 1 && position === len && { borderRightColor: color },
        index === position && { borderLeftColor: color },
      ]}
      {...restProps}
    >
      {value}
    </CharText.Animated>
  );
};
```